# Pytorch: TypeError: copy_(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Vectors

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, transformer-model

I am building my model in google colab.

I have created a custom embedding matrix

```
import torchtext.vocab as vocab

custom_embeddings = vocab.Vectors(name = 'custom_embeddings.txt')
TEXT.build_vocab(train_data, vectors = custom_embeddings)
```

Here is the code for the Encoder class:

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, 
                 input_dim, 
                 hid_dim, 
                 n_layers, 
                 n_heads, 
                 pf_dim,
                 dropout, 
                 device,
                 max_length = 100):
        super().__init__()

        self.device = device

        self.tok_embedding = nn.Embedding(input_dim, hid_dim)

        # step added for custom embedding
        self.tok_embedding.weight.data.copy_(custom_embeddings)

        self.pos_embedding = nn.Embedding(max_length, hid_dim)

        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([EncoderLayer(hid_dim, 
                                                  n_heads, 
                                                  pf_dim,
                                                  dropout, 
                                                  device) 
                                     for _ in range(n_layers)])

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

        self.scale = torch.sqrt(torch.FloatTensor([hid_dim])).to(device)

    def forward(self, src, src_mask):

        #src = [batch size, src len]
        #src_mask = [batch size, src len]

        batch_size = src.shape[0]
        src_len = src.shape[1]

        pos = torch.arange(0, src_len).unsqueeze(0).repeat(batch_size, 1).to(self.device)

        #pos = [batch size, src len]

        src = self.dropout((self.tok_embedding(src) * self.scale) + self.pos_embedding(pos))

        #src = [batch size, src len, hid dim]

        for layer in self.layers:
            src = layer(src, src_mask)

        #src = [batch size, src len, hid dim]

        return src
```

Now when I am trying to create the Encoder object, I am getting error for the custom embedding I have used.

```
enc = Encoder(INPUT_DIM, 
              HID_DIM, 
              ENC_LAYERS, 
              ENC_HEADS, 
              ENC_PF_DIM, 
              ENC_DROPOUT, 
              device)
```

Error decscription:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-06d3631c029b> in <module>()
     18               ENC_PF_DIM,
     19               ENC_DROPOUT,
---> 20               device)
     21 
     22 dec = Decoder(OUTPUT_DIM, 

<ipython-input-59-6c2f23451d01> in __init__(self, input_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, n_heads, pf_dim, dropout, device, max_length)
     16 
     17         # step added for custom embedding
---> 18         self.tok_embedding.weight.data.copy_(custom_embeddings)
     19 
     20         self.pos_embedding = nn.Embedding(max_length, hid_dim)

TypeError: copy_(): argument 'other' (position 1) must be Tensor, not Vectors
```

Could you please help me to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue.

Solution:
custom_embeddings is a vector object so we can not .copy_ from it as it is not tensor.

using TEXT.vocab.vectors in place of custom_embeddings resolved the issue.

updated code:

```
# step added for custom embedding
self.tok_embedding.weight.data.copy_(TEXT.vocab.vectors)
```